# How do I print an error message to user screen instead of standard out in JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, error-handling

I was wondering how I can print an error message to the user in the case he/she entered the wrong passowrd in JSP. Given that I have the form set up and validation works, I am trying to add this one check but the output is printed to the standard out ie console, however, I would like for it to be printed to the screen that the user is viewing. Here's my code for authentication:

```
public boolean verify (String username, String password) {

        if (!password.equals("1234")) {
            System.out.println("Wrong password!\n");
            return false;
        } 

        return true;        
    }
```

EDIT: LoginProcessing.java calls the method above and checks the boolean value (logedin), if it is not set I execute the code below, but it still doesn't print to the screen where user can see it.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

// skipping initializations for brevity

if (logedin) { 
// do stuff 
}else {
            System.out.println("Wrong password!\n");
            response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
            return;
        }
    }
```

EDIT 2:  Here's what my code looks like in login.html to which I redirect in the code above from the doPost() method, except I removed the println() method.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Login Using JSP</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="login" method="post">
    Please enter your username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Please enter your password:<input type="password" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<c:if test="${!loggedin}">
    Sorry. Wrong user name or password
</c:if>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From where is this method called? From a servlet?

Comment: write back the message in the `HttpResponse#getWriter()` object from Servlet `doPost()` method.

Comment: @JBNizet Yes, from LoginProcessing.java servlet.

Comment: @user3218114 I make the changes in HttpRequest as you indicated, please see the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your servlet method:

```
// check the credentials
boolean loggedIn = verify(username, password);

// store the result in a request attribute, so that the JSP can retrieve it
request.setAttribute("loggedIn", loggedIn);

// let a JSP display the result
request.getRequestDispatcher("/loginResult.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

In the JSP (using the [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)), test the value of the loggedIn request parameter:

```
<c:if test="${loggedIn}">
    Congratulations: you're now logged in.
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!loggedIn}">
    Sorry. Wrong user name or password
</c:if>
```

Comment: I did as you indicated but Eclipse is complaining that (c:if) is an unknown tag.  And always prints the Wrong password message to screen.

Comment: Have you followed the link to the JSTL in my answer. Have you read the page, added the appropriate jar files to your application, and added the appropriate taglib directive to your JSP? What does the generated HTML code look like?

Comment: I made the edit2 and included the code from my html where I want the message printed.  I looked int the documentation but was wondering if there is a way to do the same thing without using the new library since the code will be uploaded to the server that might not have this library enabled.

Comment: The server doesn't need to have any library installed. It has to be included into your webapp, under WEB-INF/lib, as any other webapp library. And yes, you should definitely use it. Of course you can do the same with scriptlets, but scriptlets shouldn't be used for years and years. Use the right tools. And re-read my answer and my comment, since you haven't done anything except adding the c:if block.

Comment: I added the jstl-1.2.jar to WEB-INF/lib directory of my project, included <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %> to my login.jsp but I still get the "Unknown tab(c:if)" message.

Comment: Don't rely on eclipse to validate that your settings are correct (eclipse sucks at doing that). Deploy your app, and test if he tags work.

Comment: I ran the app and it displays the Wrong Password message right away since !logged in is not set so the message evaluates to true even before the user enters any input.

Comment: I'm creating sessions in loginProcessing.java with request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user); maybe I could check for if sessions exists and loggedin set to false, then print Wrong password message, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that.

Comment: Take some time learning the JSP EL. You could do the first test with `loggedIn != null && !loggedIn`.

Comment: thanks for your help, I finally got it to work.  I also checked out your site NinjaSquad and I think you guys are awesome, keep up the good work!